# Wilson scoring doesn't factor in negative votes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm

I'm using the wilson scoring algorithm (code below) and realized it doesn't factor in negative votes.

Example:

```
Upvotes  Downvotes  Score
1        0          0.2070
0        0          0
0        1          0 <--- this is wrong
```

That isn't correct as the negative net votes should have a lower score.

```
def calculate_wilson_score(up_votes, down_votes)
  require 'cmath'
  total_votes = up_votes + down_votes
  return 0 if total_votes == 0

  z = 1.96
  positive_ratio = (1.0*up_votes)/total_votes
  score = (positive_ratio + z*z/(2*total_votes) - z * CMath.sqrt((positive_ratio*(1-positive_ratio)+z*z/(4*total_votes))/total_votes))/(1+z*z/total_votes)
  score.round(3)
end
```

Update:

Here is a description of the [Wilson scoring confidence interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Please add a link and description of what Wilson scoring is. I don't know the term

Comment: Also I think 0 is the correct lower bound for a fairly certain "real" fraction of upvotes/total votes. Not sure what you were expecting, but you can only get values between 0 and 1

Comment: @NiklasB. If that's the case, then something that has negative votes would rank the same as something that has 0 votes. Doesn't seem right.

Comment: It seems excatly right because you are estimating the fraction `upvotes / total_votes`, which is zero if you have no upvotes, no matter how many total votes you have. Wilson score is a pessimistic estimate, so without any votes we have to assume that it has a 0 upvote fraction, so it *has* to rank the same as something with multiple negative votes. By the way, the Wikipedia description is totally unuseful to see what's going on, at least to me

Answer (score 0):

The Wilson Score Lower Confidence Bound posted will certainly take negative votes into account, although the lower confidence bound will not get lower than zero, which is perfectly fine. This approximation for ranking items is generally used for identifying the highest ranked items on a best-rated list. It thus may have undesirable properties when looking at the lowest ranked items, which are the type you are describing.

This method of ranking items was popularized by Evan Miller in [a post on how not to sort by average rating](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html), although he later [stated](http://www.evanmiller.org/bayesian-average-ratings.html)

> The solution I proposed previously — using the lower bound of a confidence interval around the mean — is what computer programmers call a hack. It works not because it is a universally optimal solution, but because it roughly corresponds to our intuitive sense of what we'd like to see at the top of a best-rated list: items with the smallest probability of being bad, given the data.

If you are genuinely interested in analyzing the lowest ranked items on a list, I would suggest either using the *upper* confidence bound, or using a Bayesian rating systems as described in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30111531/3884938